# Delete all access database table data

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I have an access database that I am manipulating with C#.

I have connected to it, retrieved a data-set from it and can add rows to a table. Now I am trying to clear a table and I am unable to get it to work.

I have tried `TRUNCATE TABLE table_name` but that throws an exception saying that I must use either `DELETE, INSERT, PROCEDURE, SELECT or UPDATE` and I have tried `Delete FROM table_name` However that throws an `DBConcurrenceyException`.

Here is what I have to tried to clear the table:

```
private void ClearBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbDataAdapter dtaAdpTestTableClear = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    OleDbCommand command;

    command = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM TestTable", con);

    dtaAdpTestTableClear.DeleteCommand = command;

    foreach (DataRow row in dsWCSDHDB.Tables["TestTable"].Rows)
    {
        row.Delete();
    }

    dtaAdpTestTableClear.Update(dsWCSDHDB.Tables["TestTable"]);
}
```

My other add method

```
private void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbDataAdapter dtaAdpTestTableInsertNewRow = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    OleDbCommand command;

    // Create the InsertCommand.
    // This is needed as DataAdaptor.InsertCommand() is called during the update to insert the row into the database. It requires an insert query
    command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO TestTable (id, someData) " +"VALUES (?, ?)", con); //We create a dbcommand the command is, Querytype, what we are doing with it, what table, (columns we are using), concat, Values we will be adding(as ? for now as we will pass this data in latter), connection to the database 

    command.Parameters.Add("id", OleDbType.Char, 5, "id"); //this is where we add a parameter to the command function. we add one per column in the row (columns we are using name, value type, column length, source column, these parameters will replace the ? in the query above 
    command.Parameters.Add("someData", OleDbType.VarChar, 40, "someData");

    dtaAdpTestTableInsertNewRow.InsertCommand = command;// we attach this command to the Insert command function of the adapter that we are using

    //Create the new row
    DataRow  row = dsWCSDHDB.Tables["TestTable"].NewRow(); //Create a new empty row that is formated for the TestTable table
    row["someData"] = AddValueTextBox.Text.ToString();// add in the values 

    //Add the new row to the dataset table
    dsWCSDHDB.Tables["TestTable"].Rows.Add(row); //adds this new row to the clients dataset

    //Updates the database table with the values of the clients dataset Table
    //For this to work you need to build a proper data adapter that is using a query taylered for the table you are using. 
    //Unfortunately although it would be nice to be able to add and use tables to the database with out changing the code you cant build a generic one that works for all tables in the database. 
    //this is because different tables can have different fields and column lengths .
    //there is a example of how to build one below 

    //Update the database table with the values of the clients dataset Table
    dtaAdpTestTableInsertNewRow.Update(dsWCSDHDB.Tables["TestTable"]);   // using the adapter that we created above we update the database with the clients dataset.
}
```

Comment: Your command deletes a table yet your also trying to delete the rows at the same time?! You need to do one or the other

Comment: Why use a `OleDbDataAdapter` when you can just issue the command using the `OleDbCommand`?

Comment: You don't really need an adapter, just execute command.ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: Im not trying to delete the table I am trying to deleat all the rows in the table.

I dont know how to do it with out a data adaptor

Comment: command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will just need to call `ExecuteNonQuery`

```
private void ClearBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string comand = "DELETE FROM TestTable";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(comand, con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

Comment: tryed that however the line cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() gives me an error

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.

Comment: @SkylineGodzilla use sqlcommand which is in latest update of my answer

Comment: is your connection string proper?

Comment: @Mostafiz well thats a first I got a purple underline.
my app is setup to use an OleDB conection not a sql conection.as its conecting to an access database not an sql database can not convert oledbconection to sqlconection

Comment: @SkylineGodzilla but `OleDbCommand` should work which I have come back again, ok I am checking again

Comment: @SkylineGodzilla check update I have added with `DELETE` comand without trancate this time should work

Comment: OK that kinda works It clears the table but now when I try to add somthing to the table the app now crashes. An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Update requires a valid DeleteCommand when passed DataRow collection with deleted rows. 

I will add that method to my post

Comment: @SkylineGodzilla check out this thread why this exception happen and what is solution https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9a5167c5-e83d-4314-9a61-8a768a0ca730/update-requires-a-valid-deletecommand-when-passed-datarow-collection-with-deleted-rows?forum=Vsexpressvb

Comment: Ok im going to carry on with this tomorrow im going to bed now thanks for your help

Comment: Doesn't Access use the syntax `DELETE * FROM TestTable`?